# How to realise a two-sided Student's t-test for a slope coefficient (b)(raster) in R?

Tags: r, time-series, t-test, f-test

For a projet, I have to analyse NDVI trends over times (between 2001 and 2020). My teacher asked me to use the same method as presented by Leroux et al. (2017) ( https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rse.2017.01.014). I have the linear model : iNDVI = a + b*Time and know I have to test the consitency of the trends, it can be done with a two-sided Student's t-test (as presented by Leroux et al. (2017)) of with a f-test. But as it is a raster I can't manage to find a solution. Here is my code for the linear model:

```
filenames_RAIN<- list.files(inpath_RAIN,pattern=".tif$",full.names = TRUE)
filenames_NDVI<- list.files(inpath,pattern=".tif$",full.names = TRUE)

date_GS = (read_excel(path_excel))
date_GS%>%mutate_all(as.character)
year<-colnames(date_GS)
for (i in year)
{
  
  date_GS_year <- as.list(date_GS[,i])
  list <- as.list(date_GS_year[[1]])
  it  <- 0
  res <- c()
  for(j in list){
    it  <- it + 1
    res <- append(res, filenames_NDVI[grepl(pattern = j, x = filenames_NDVI)])
  }
  
  all_NDVI_stack<- stack(res)
  all_NDVI_stack <- all_NDVI_stack/100000000
  NDVI_max <- max(all_NDVI_stack)
  writeRaster( NDVI_max, paste(outpath,"/MODIS_NDVImax_",i, sep = ""),format = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)
}
filenames_NDVI_max<- list.files(outpath,pattern=".tif$",full.names = TRUE)
NDVI_all_max <- stack(filenames_NDVI_max)
timestamps <- 1:nlayers(NDVI_all_max)
plot(timestamps)
lm_intercept <- calc(NDVI_all_max, fun = function(x) {
  if (all(is.na(x)))
    return(NA)
  else
    return(coef(lm(x ~ timestamps))[1])
})
lm_slope <- calc(NDVI_all_max, fun = function(x) {
  if (all(is.na(x)))
    return(NA)
  else
    return(coef(lm(x ~ timestamps))[2])
})
iNDVI <- lm_intercept + (lm_slope*19)
```